# android gradle build failing with jenkins on cloudbees

Tags: android, jenkins, gradle, cloudbees

I use gradle with the android plugin 0.4.2 to build my project - which works fine - just not on cloudbees - there I get the following error:

```
07:10:47.168 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] org.gradle.api.GradleScriptException: A problem occurred evaluating root project 'FAST Build'.
07:10:47.169 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:54)
07:10:47.169 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl.apply(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:127)
07:10:47.170 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.configuration.BuildScriptProcessor.evaluate(BuildScriptProcessor.java:38)
07:10:47.171 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.configuration.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:43)
07:10:47.172 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProject.java:466)
07:10:47.173 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProject.java:77)
07:10:47.173 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.configuration.ProjectEvaluationConfigurer.execute(ProjectEvaluationConfigurer.java:23)
07:10:47.174 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.configuration.ProjectEvaluationConfigurer.execute(ProjectEvaluationConfigurer.java:21)
07:10:47.175 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.Actions$CompositeAction.execute(Actions.java:78)
07:10:47.176 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.Actions$TransformingActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:130)
07:10:47.177 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.configure(AbstractProject.java:442)
07:10:47.183 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.allprojects(AbstractProject.java:437)
07:10:47.184 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultBuildConfigurer.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurer.java:40)
07:10:47.184 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:142)
07:10:47.185 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:113)
07:10:47.186 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:81)
07:10:47.187 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:38)
07:10:47.188 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessGradleLauncherActionExecuter.execute(InProcessGradleLauncherActionExecuter.java:39)
07:10:47.191 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessGradleLauncherActionExecuter.execute(InProcessGradleLauncherActionExecuter.java:25)
07:10:47.192 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:50)
07:10:47.193 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:171)
07:10:47.195 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:201)
07:10:47.197 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:174)
07:10:47.200 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:170)
07:10:47.263 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:139)
07:10:47.264 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
07:10:47.271 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
07:10:47.272 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:48)
07:10:47.273 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
07:10:47.274 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:39)
07:10:47.275 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:50)
07:10:47.277 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:32)
07:10:47.279 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:26)
07:10:47.280 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Caused by: org.gradle.api.plugins.PluginInstantiationException: Could not create plugin of type 'AppPlugin'.
07:10:47.282 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginRegistry.loadPlugin(DefaultPluginRegistry.java:65)
07:10:47.284 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultProjectsPluginContainer.providePlugin(DefaultProjectsPluginContainer.java:106)
07:10:47.286 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultProjectsPluginContainer.addPluginInternal(DefaultProjectsPluginContainer.java:71)
07:10:47.288 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultProjectsPluginContainer.apply(DefaultProjectsPluginContainer.java:37)
07:10:47.290 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.applyPlugin(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:101)
07:10:47.292 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.access$200(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:32)
07:10:47.294 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction$3.run(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:72)
07:10:47.296 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.execute(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:114)
07:10:47.299 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.apply(AbstractProject.java:854)
07:10:47.300 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.Project$apply.call(Unknown Source)
07:10:47.302 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.ProjectScript.apply(ProjectScript.groovy:34)
07:10:47.304 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.Script$apply.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
07:10:47.306 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at build_4qb0i7tbmj7s6d3ji53ui92pv3.run(/scratch/jenkins/workspace/FAST Build/build.gradle:9)
07:10:47.308 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:52)
07:10:47.309 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    ... 32 more
07:10:47.311 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/gradle/tooling/provider/model/ToolingModelBuilderRegistry
07:10:47.311 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.DependencyInjectingInstantiator.selectConstructor(DependencyInjectingInstantiator.java:97)
07:10:47.312 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.DependencyInjectingInstantiator.newInstance(DependencyInjectingInstantiator.java:58)
07:10:47.313 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginRegistry.loadPlugin(DefaultPluginRegistry.java:63)
07:10:47.314 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    ... 45 more
07:10:47.315 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.gradle.tooling.provider.model.ToolingModelBuilderRegistry
07:10:47.316 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    ... 48 more
07:10:47.317 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]
```

I get it for this project:
https://github.com/ligi/FAST

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this new documentation now finally shed some light into how to do what I wanted to do
http://developer.cloudbees.com/bin/view/DEV/AndroidGradleBuilds

Answer (score 0):

gradle 1.6 is available on cloudbees, and it's up to user to manage the tools installations to get the adequate versions for job configuration. => http://[account].ci.cloudbees.com/configure

Comment: thanks, but I only see maven and ant there - no configuration options for gradle!?

Comment: You have to install the gradle plugin in jenkins first.